React - Some data rendering correctly but some returning "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ...)"
I am working on an online magazine in React (similar to Vogue, Elle, etc). I have a JS file (which acts as an API for the data) that contains an array of objects. Each object represents the data for a specific issue (or story, if you may).
export const feedData = [
  {
    key: 1,
    category: "Trending",
    title: "Why Tyler ICU Is Being Accused Of Plagiarism",
    image:
      "https://netstorage-briefly.akamaized.net/images/3dff571b0ed0cdb9.jpg?imwidth=900",
    issueTextP1:
      "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit...",
    issueTextP2:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit...",
    author: "John Smith",
    date: "01 September 2023",
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    category: "Watch",
    title: "Shekhinah Releases 'Tides' Music Video",
    image:
      "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-0X5mYBEnDbWDOVap-U2RQjA-t500x500.jpg",
    issueTextP1:
      "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit...",
    issueTextP2:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit...",
    author: "John Smith",
    date: "01 September 2023",
  }}
  {
    key: 3,
    category: "Opinion",
    title: "Why Is Everyone Suddenly Obsessed With Suits? I Tried to Find Out",
    image:
      "...",
    issueTextP1:
      "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit...",
    issueTextP2:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit...",
    author: "John Smith,
    date: "01 September 2023",
  },

As you can see all of these objects are identical. Each object represents an issue, so I am trying to display the object's contents on screen (in it's own page using useParams).
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { feedData } from "./FeedData";

export default function SingleIssue() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);

  const { title } = useParams();
  const product = feedData.find((product) => product.title === title);

  return (
    <div className="single-issue">
      <div className="issue-hero">
        <div id="issue-heading">
          {title} <br />
          <span>
            By {product.author} <br />
            {product.date}
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id="issue-image">
          <img src={product.image} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="issue-text-ads">
        <div className="issue-text">
          {product.issueTextP1} <br />
          <br /> {product.issueTextP2} <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

For some of the issues (or objects) it's rendering everything just fine (i.e displays all the content correctly) but for some it returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ...)" for all the values (author, date, image, etc) which results in a blank page.
Error image:
Additionally, here's the link to the issue page:
<Link to={`/issue/${props.title}`} className="link">

and here is the route:
<Route path="/issue/:title" element={<SingleIssue />} />

I tried to console.log each of the objects and each of them display the values correctly (i.e no undefined values)
const logMap = feedData.map((item) => console.log(item));

Once again, all of these objects are identical but some are not rendering, so what am I doing wrong? I am new to React, please help.

The error implies that the find() operation didn't find a matching record.  When the error occurs, what is the observed runtime value of title?  Is it what you expect?  What observed runtime record in feedData do you expect it to match?

@David It is indeed a problem with title, thanks a lot

If you get all those TypeError, it's because no product is found when executing the following line:
const product = feedData.find((product) => product.title === title);

I suspect the reason is that you are trying to match product's title with a string coming in the URL, which may have suffered some transformation. I suggest adding console.log(title) just above the line above and verify the string you are searching exactly matches product title. My guess is you'll see a slightly different string when the title contains special characters such as ' or ?, as you are not even URL-encoding the strings when building the URL.
A possible solution would be to apply some transformation to the title that makes it more URL-friendly (for example, remove special characters and convert to kebab case). Of course, you'd have to apply the same transformation on feedData.find.
So:
<Link to={`/issue/${transformTitle(props.title)}`} className="link">

and:
const product = feedData.find((product) => transformTitle(product.title) === title);


By the way, your transformTitle function could be as simple as calling encodeURIComponent(), but I suggested kebab-case transformation as it makes the URL look more elegant

Thank you so much for the help. I encoded the string and that fixed the error, rookie mistake

The find() method in arrays returns the first element that matches a specified condition. If no match is found, it returns undefined. Attempting to access any property of undefined will result in a TypeError, "Cannot read properties of undefined"

The error means the product variable's value is undefined.
This can happen when the find() operator does not match any records in the array on the line const product = feedData.find((product) => product.title === title);
You should put the optional chaining (?.) operator if you don't want it to throw an error, or you should validate if it's undefined or not before rendering it's value on the DOM.

Alternatively you can use Try Catch block for error handling as the product title is undefined in your case.
find method is returning undefined
  const product = feedData.find((product) => product.title === title);

    if (product) {
      console.log("Found product:", product);
    } else {
      console.log("Product not found");
    }

